# How can I make the browser know that the page has finished "loading" when using window.open and writing HTML directly to the new page?

Tags: javascript

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyEYRM) of the sample code (Warning - opens a new window on loading).

The sample code:

```
var exampleWin = window.open("about:blank", "example");
var docMarkup = "<!doctype html><html><head><title>test</title></head>" + 
"<body><p>Why is the browser still transferring data? How can I tell it to stop?</p></body></html>";
exampleWin.document.write(docMarkup);
```

It works fine, except that the newly opened window has the browser loading spinner running forever. If I press stop and refresh on the newly opened page, the spinner stops.

How can I tell the page that there is no more data coming and make the spinner stop?

EDIT: In Firefox

Comment: I don't see any spinner in chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`document.close`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-98948567):

```
exampleWin.document.close();
```

… which will close the output stream that `document.write` writes to so the browser will know it is done.